# Poll component not showing Home link in breadcrumb

Tags: joomla, links, navigation, breadcrumbs

With the joomla's default Poll component, when I go to vote, and it takes me to the results page, the Home link disappears from the Breadcrumb navigation. Is there a way to make the breadcrumb navigation always show Home when in the poll results page?

NOTE: We're still running an older version: Joomla! 1.0.15

UPDATE: Checked the CHANGELOG.php, and on June 23, 2006, this issue was supposedly fixed. However, it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the version you are using it is the Intended to work that way. I suppose you could switch to Joomla 1.5 there is no breaking changes between the two versions, you can have a look here http://deeptechtons.com/ on the front page click the results the breadcrumb will display the title of the Poll itself which is neat.

Comment: Yeah i did a test of 1.5 and that issue does not exist anymore. However, we have a lot of content and very sensitive information, and it's a bit risky to attempt a move to 1.5 atm.

Comment: I may recommend doing it on a test bed & then put it into production. Before putting it into production do rigorous test with various closely related people to report the error they might have faced